# Increase Max connections in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, connection, max

My Server Config :
CPU - 16 core
RAM - 64 GB
Storage : 2 TB
OS : CentOs 64 Bit

I have DB and java application on the same server.

My postgres config file has the following:
max_connections = 9999
shared_buffers = 6GB

However, when i check DB via show max_connections it shows only 500.

How can i increase the max_connections value ?

Comment: You might have more luck getting an answer on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: 10000 connections is an insanely high number and up to Postgres 13 more or less unrealistic. Why do you need that many connection? Are you creating one connection for every named user? There is a slight chance that this might work in an "acceptable" manner with Postgres 14

Answer (score 1):

Either you forgot to remove the comment (`#`) at the beginning of the `postgresql.conf` line, or you didn't restart PostgreSQL.

But a setting of 500 is already much too high, unless you have some 100 cores in the machine and an I/O system to match. Use a connection pool.